# Problems removing custom Qgraphicsitem from Qgraphicsscene

Tags: qt, qt5, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I have subclassed both a Qgraphicsscene and a Qgraphicsitem, it seems it works but trying to remove the items by subclass recognition don't works. 
This delete the items:

```
void debugSceneItemscuatrobis()
{
    QList<QGraphicsItem *> allitems = items();
        foreach(auto item, allitems) {
            removeItem(item);
        }
    }
```

But this doesn't, it recognizes there are items but doesn't remove them, tryed different posseibilities but couldn't make it works.

```
void debugSceneItemscuatrotris()
{
    QList<QGraphicsItem *> allitems = items();
        foreach(auto item, allitems) {
        if(item->type() == chord::Type) {
            removeItem(item);
            delete item;
         }
        }
    }
```

This is how the items were added by the qgraphicsitem subclass:

```
void chord::addchord(QPointF sp)
{
    scene()->addLine(sp.x(), sp.y(), sp.x()+10, sp.y()+10);
        QList<int> midics = {10, 30, 40};
      for(int i = 0; i < midics.length(); i++)
          {
        QGraphicsSimpleTextItem *item = new QGraphicsSimpleTextItem("n");
        item->setFont(QFont("omheads", 20));
        item->setPos(sp.x(), sp.y()+midics[i]);
        scene()->addItem(item);
        coso.append(item);
      }
}
```

Sorry, I'm very newbie and no programmer, those are my first subclasses. Someone knows how it could be approached? Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing more of your code I'm only guessing.  But that guess would be that when you remove an item of type `chord` you are still able to see the various `QGraphicsItem`s that were added to the scene in `chord::addchord`.  If so it's probably due to the lack of any parent/child relationship between the `chord` and those items: from the documentation for [`QGraphicsScene::removeItem(item)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#removeItem)...

> Removes the item *item* and all its children from the scene.

Try creating the parent/child relationship explicitly by changing your `chord:addchord` implementation to...

```
void chord::addchord (QPointF sp)
{
    auto *line = scene()->addLine(sp.x(), sp.y(), sp.x() + 10, sp.y() + 10);
    line->setParentItem(this);
    QList<int> midics = { 10, 30, 40 };
    for (int i = 0; i < midics.length(); i++)
    {
        QGraphicsSimpleTextItem *item = new QGraphicsSimpleTextItem("n", this);
        item->setFont(QFont("omheads", 20));
        item->setPos(sp.x(), sp.y() + midics[i]);
        scene()->addItem(item);
        coso.append(item);
    }
}
```

It might not solve all of the issues but should (hopefully) head you in the right direction.